# How to allow html tags on textarea, PHP to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, html, tags, textarea

How to allow these types of HTML tags inside the textarea for PHP into MySQL? The simple ones maybe... `<b>`, `<i>`, `<u>` etc.

Thank you.

Comment: How are they not allowed now?  If you are using `htmlspecialchars()` when putting the data back in the textarea later, there should be no issue.

Comment: [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Answer (score 4):

The php function [`strip_tags`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) can be used for stripping all html tags except for `$allowable_tags`. Which can be specified like this:

```
strip_tags($textareaUserInput, '<b><i><u>');
```

I guess it's something like this that you want. However this doesn't solve possible problems with special characters that need to be escaped.

**Also:** Have a look at [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) as @Phil suggest in his comment. This is especialy a good idea if you are worried about security loopholes like [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) and such, because [`strip_tags`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) [won't be good enough if you allow certain tags to persist](http://php.net/strip_tags#refsect1-function.strip-tags-notes).

Answer (score 0):

You can leave HTML-tags as is, because both PHP and MySQL don't have problems with that. When retrieving data from the database and place it inside the textarea, make sure to use `htmlspecialchars()` to convert characters with a special meaning to HTML-entities.
For example `<` will be converted to `&lt;`.